# How to add a background image to only specific range of cells in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an image that I want to use as a background in excel only for range A1:F26. How would I do that?
Also If I hover over the cells in range A1:F26, I should be able to click, edit and select those cells with my mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

In Excel you can select an image as a background for the
*whole sheet*, which will then be tiled and look fairly awful.
You cannot insert an image as a background to a specific cell or
a range of cells.

As a workaround you can insert a *new shape* into the sheet and
fill it up with a picture, defining it as "Picture or texture fill"
and attaching it to the range of cells using the option of
"Move and size with cells".

For a detailed description with screenshots, see the article
[How to insert a printable background image in Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1056-excel-print-background.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert Camera in the **Customize Ribbon**.
[image]

Then select the area of the table you need to add a background to and click **Camera**.

Then right-click on the Picture Format to insert the picture you need.